# Как зациклить слайдер swiper, если не хватает слайдов

Tags: javascript, swiper

Для понимания - одновременно выводится 6 слайдов, а в наличии их 8 всего. Само собой, что для корректной работы зацикливания нужно slidesPerView * 2, но столько слайдов нет. loopedSlides не срабатывает и не добавляет клоны, а может я вообще не правильно понял работу данного параметра.

```
const prewievSliderShops = new Swiper('.shops-slider', {
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    loopedSlides: 3,
    // spaceBetween: 16,
    speed: 800,
    watchOverflow: true,
    autoplay: true,
    centeredSlides: false,
    autoplay: {
                delay: 3000,
                disableOnInteraction: false,
            },
    normalizeSlideIndex: true,
    loopPreventsSliding: false,

    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.shops-slider-next',
        prevEl: '.shops-slider-prev',
    },
});
```